# Delete a element using regex from list in python

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have a list in python

```
a=['one_foo','two_foo','bar_foo']
```

Expected output:

```
['one','two','bar']
```

I tried doing by first converting list into string and then using regex

```
import re
re.sub("_.*$","", str(a))
```

I know converting list to string is incorrect way to achieve this task,may be is there any elegant way without converting it to string?

Comment: Are you tied to regex or are you willing to consider other solutions?

Comment: NO. we can use other solutions as well

Comment: What do you want to do with a string like `"test_foo_bar"`? Should the result be `"test_foo"` or `"test"` ?

Comment: @PM2Ring In that case the result should be "test_foo" (or just remove last string containing '_')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
a = ['one_foo', 'two_foo', 'bar_foo']

res = [x.rsplit('_', 1)[0] for x in a]

['one', 'two', 'bar']
```

In general, regex solutions tend to underperform `str` methods for similar operations.

Comment: Perfect solution!, but how `rsplit` is different with 'split'

Comment: `split` works from the left. `rsplit` works from the right. The `1` argument means we only perform one split.